# Managing certificates with WCF

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, certificate, nettcpbinding

We have a central WCF service that we are exposing via netTcpBinding for duplex comms with clients.

We only want to allow certain computers on the internet to communicate with this WCF service. The route we are going down is to use X509 certificates to secure the transport layer and to provide client authentication, like this:

```
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
    <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
  </security>
```

At the moment we're calling "MakeCert" to generate X509 certs, and having to specify  `certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"` to get round the fact that we generated our own self-signed certificates.

My question is how should we go about managing client certificates? We don't want to get each client to buy their own certificate - there could be hundreds of them and this isn't an option. I suppose we want to act as our own "root authority", but I'm not sure how to go about this...

Comment: If your question is how to set up and use your own CA then the question belongs to Server Fault.

Comment: Well if setting up our own CA is the solution to this problem (is it?) then maybe that is my question...

Comment: Yes I think it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make every client buy its certificate from a trusted certificate provider like Verisign, your other 2 options is either generate self-signed certificates like you have been doing  (should only be used for testing) or create your own PKI (private key infrastructure).

I think creating your own PKI, in your case, is the way to go. Like others have said in the comments:

1. Start by setting up a machine as a certificate authority:

   - Install Active Directory Certificate Services (Server Roles)
   - Configure it as root CA
   - Configure cryptography, name and validity for that CA
2. Then make clients request certificates from that CA.
3. You aprove the certificate from a CA point of view.
4. Client installs the certificate.
5. Adjust WCF configuration to make use of CA and the certificates

Hope that helps.